# $\lim_{n\to ∞} \left[\frac{f\left( x +\frac1n\right)}{ f(x)}\right]^n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

Could anyone solve this problem for me?

Let f be a positive differentiable function on the internal $\left[\,0,\infty\right)$.

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \left[\frac{f\left( x +\frac1n\right)}{ f(x)}\right]^n$$

I have been told to take log, but after taking log what to do I am not able to understand.

Comment: Do you have any assumptions about $f$?

Comment: This depends on $f$. For $f(x) = x$, the answer is $0$. For $f(x)= a^x$, the answer is $a$. Etc.

Comment: Is there any use of those brackets around f or are they normal one? Seems like most of the floor function notation used in india.

Comment: @circonflexe: if $f(x)=x$, then then answer would be $e^{1/x}$, no?

Comment: is it continuous ?

Comment: edited. please see.

Comment: @Mann those brackets are around the entire quantity.. it is used to indicate whole to the power 'n'

Comment: @Shalop: indeed, sorry I was mistaken by the $a^x$ case into taking limit relative to $x$.

Comment: Ah, this hint is precious indeed. Since you know $f$ to be differentiable, look for a derivative somewhere. Hint: use first-order Taylor expansion for $f(x+1/n)$.

Comment: i see . thanks..:)

Comment: @circonflexe: you just beat me to it.... I just took too much time in writing it explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write $f(x+\frac{1}{n}) = f(x)+\frac{1}{n}f'(x)+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$, and you get that $$\lim \bigg(\frac{f(x+\frac{1}{n})}{f(x)}\bigg)^n = \lim\bigg(\frac{f(x)+\frac{1}{n}f'(x)}{f(x)}\bigg)^n = \lim \bigg(1+\frac{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}{n}\bigg)^n = e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}$$

Positivity of $f$ is needed to ensure that the denominator is non-vanishing.

Comment: Sorry but can you please tell me why $f(x+\frac{1}{n})$ can be written like that.

Comment: @HasanSaad: it is a well-known theorem in elementary real analysis that for any differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we can write $f(x+h) = f(x)+hf'(x)+O(h^2)$. However, now that I look at it, I think that egreg's answer is better than mine.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I kind of didn't notice that you used $\frac{1}{n}$ as $h$.

Comment: @Shalop....can you please explain why the term $O(1/n^2)$ is omitted in evaluating the limit...I know $O(1/n^2)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Now in the limit there is a $n$ on the power of that expression ...How can I manage that..? If we just omit that $O(1/n^2)$ term, does the limit remain same....(here is a $n$ on the power)....can you please explain...

Comment: It does not contribute because it decays more quickly than $1/n$. See answer below by egreg

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can take the logarithm; since $f$ is assumed to be positive, we can consider $g(x)=\log f(x)$. Taking the logarithm of the sequence you want to compute the limit of, we are led to
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n(g(x+1/n)-g(x))=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{g(x+1/n)-g(x)}{1/n}=g'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$
because $f$ is differentiable, so $g$ is differentiable as well and we can apply the chain rule.

Therefore your limit is
$$
\lim_{n\to ∞}\biggl[\frac{f\left( x +\frac{1}{n}\right)}{f(x)}\biggr]^n=
\exp\left(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)
$$