# How to find this limit.

Tags: limits

I encountered the following limit:
$\;\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}{\left(\frac{f\left(t+h\right)}{f\left(t\right)}\right)^{\frac1h}}=e^{\frac{f'\left(t\right)}{f\left(t\right)}}.$ Assume $\,f\,$ is analytic.
It's very much difficult for me to do that. Please help.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273902/lim-n-to-%E2%88%9E-left-fracf-left-x-frac1n-right-fx-rightn/

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\left(\frac{f(t+h)}{f(t)}\right)^{1/h}=\left(1+h\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{hf(t)}\right)^{1/h}=(1+hg)^{1/h}\to e^g.$$

Remains to show why you can replace $g$ by $\dfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $t$, then $f(t+h)=f(t)+h(f'(t)+o(1))$. $\lim_{h \to 0}(1+\alpha h)^{1 \over h} = e^\alpha$ (this is a theorem or the very definition of exponent, depending on how your course is built).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Start with $$A=\Big(\frac{f(t+h)}{f(t)}\Big)^{1/h}$$ As Your Ad Here suggested, take logarithms $$\log(A)=\frac 1 h\times \log\Big(\frac{f(t+h)}{f(t)}\Big)$$ Now, consider Taylor expansion around $h=0$ $$f(t+h)=f(t)+h f'(t)+O\left(h^2\right)\approx f(t)+h f'(t)$$ So $$\log\Big(\frac{f(t+h)}{f(t)}\Big)\approx\log\Big(\frac{f(t)+h f'(t)}{f(t)}\Big)=\log\Big(1+\frac{h f'(t)}{f(t)}\Big)\approx \frac{h f'(t)}{f(t)}$$ $$\log(A)\approx\frac 1 h \times \frac{h f'(t)}{f(t)}=\frac{ f'(t)}{f(t)}$$